# Changing font size for drop down menu using Magento 2

Tags: css, less, magento2

I have a problem to find out where I can change the top drop down menu font size.
I should use less file or css file to it, right? But where?

Answer (score 0):

For change your css try this.

Go to this path = ***Magento-2/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_block.xml***

And add your ***custom.css*** like under the code.

1.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<css src="css/mycustom.css"/>
</head>
```

2. And add your css file here

path = ***Magento-2/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/mycustom.css than after apply your code.***